# NullReferenceException from Any method in production that I cannot reproduce locally

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, nullreferenceexception

When I look on our MVC4 website which, among other things, can be used to make a Timetable and go to /Timetable I see the error message:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object. (...)
>
> Stack trace:
>   [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   ASP._Page_Views_Timetable_Index_cshtml.b__5(Schedule s) +54
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.Any(IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>   +146    ASP._Page_Views_Timetable_Index_cshtml.Execute() +4057    System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +198
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage() +17
>   System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +64 (...)

This is not desirable. Unfortunately, I cannot put the compilation mode into debug in production, and locally I cannot reproduce the error. I do want to fix it and I hope that someone here can help me. I'll provide my attempt at solving the issue and hope you would be willing to think along:

Looking at the stack trace above I see an `Any()` call, and there are only two `Any()` calls on the `Timetable/Index.cshtml` and one in the controller.

We have a Schedule and a Proposal model: (Schedule is used to store a Date, User and State, and the Proposal is used if an user wants to change dates with another user).

```
public class Schedule : IValidatableObject {
    [Key]
    public int ScheduleId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public ScheduleState State { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Proposal> ProposalsAsSender { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Proposal> ProposalsAsReceiver { get; set; }
}

public class Proposal {
    public int ProposalId { get; set; }
    public ProposalState State { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ProposalsAsSender")]
    public virtual Schedule SenderSchedule { get; set; }
    [InverseProperty("ProposalsAsReceiver")]
    public virtual Schedule ReceiverSchedule { get; set; }
}
```

There are the following two methods on the Model `Proposal`:

```
public ICollection<Proposal> GetAssociatedProposals()
{
    return ProposalsAsSender.Concat(ProposalsAsReceiver).ToList();
}

public ICollection<Proposal> GetActiveAssociatedProposals()
{
    return GetAssociatedProposals()
            .Where(p => p.State == ProposalState.Active)
            .Where(p => p.ReceiverSchedule.State == ScheduleState.Active)
            .Where(p => p.SenderSchedule.State == ScheduleState.Active)
            .ToList();
}
```

What I see locally is that this method always returns an empty list, but not `null`. (Can it return `null`?).

There is also a `TimetableController` with one method:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var dates = Schedule.GetCorveeDatesNextThirtyDays(); // returns dates that are not weekends
    var schedulesNextThirtyDays = db.Schedules.Where(s =>  
                             dates.Contains(s.Date)).ToList();

    var schedules = schedulesNextThirtyDays.Where(s => s.State == 
                             ScheduleState.Active).ToList();

    if (!schedules.Any(s => s.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date))) //Any in controller
    {
        var todays_schedule = schedulesNextThirtyDays.Where(s => s.State == 
                ScheduleState.Completed).FirstOrDefault(s => dates.Contains(s.Date));
        if(todays_schedule != null)
            schedules.Add(todays_schedule);
    }

    return View(new DatesAndSchedulesViewModel(dates, schedules));
}
```

Where `DatesAndSchedulesViewModel` consists of an `ICollection<Schedule> Schedules` and `ICollection<DateTime> Dates` which are set in the constructor.

And on the Timetable view that has the `DatesAndSchedulesViewModel` as `Model` we have the following code that happens after a `schedule != null` check:

```
@if (Model.Schedules.Any(s => s.User.Name.Equals(User.Identity.Name))) //First Any() on view
{
    if (schedule.State == ScheduleState.Active)
    {
        if (schedule.GetActiveAssociatedProposals().Any()) //Second Any() on view
        {
            <span>Do something</span>
        }
    }
}
```

I know that Linq's `Any()` can throw a NullReferenceException if it is done on `null`. What I was wondering is if `schedule.GetActiveAssociatedProposals()` on the `Timetable` view could possibly return `null`, and therefore throw the exception above? Or can `if (!schedules.Any(s => s.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date)))` in the controller do a check on `null`?

If so, the problem might be solved by checking if some properties are `null` before doing the checks. I hope someone can tell me if this is indeed the case, and give me a start on how to implement `null`-checks!

Comment: I recall the pain of this type of error and the hours I would spend trying to recreate certain errors my users were seeing.  Cameron is on the money below, but to share we have now implemented Intellitrace in Production and whilst only available with VS Ultimate, I would never go back, it has cut out so much wasted time in debugging.  See the error with stacktrace and double click to go to the line of code causing the issue.  Worth a look for future consideration!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any can return null, but in this case it's the lambda that's throwing null.

From your stacktrace:

```
ASP._Page_Views_Timetable_Index_cshtml.b__5(Schedule s) +54
```

`b__5` indicates that is an internal class that was created by the lambda used inside the `Any`.

```
if (!schedules.Any(s => s.Date.Equals(DateTime.Now.Date)))
```

My guess is that `s` is null so the list isn't empty, but contains a null element.

Edit: Oops, wrong `Any`

```
@if (Model.Schedules.Any(s => s.User.Name.Equals(User.Identity.Name)))
```

This makes more sense. `User` could be null, or `Name` could be null.

Comment: `b_5` indicates an internal class. :-) Wow, how do you know if you don't mind me asking? Having asked that, the `Schedules` table does not allow NULLs for all columns, so I don't understand how the `db.Schedules.Where(s => dates.Contains(s.Date)).ToList()` could possibly contain a null element?

Comment: Also `Schedule`'s `UserId` and `User`'s `Name` cannot be NULL.

Comment: @user2609980 I just recognize the names the C# compiler uses for lambdas. Double underscores are a good sign.

Comment: Would it help to do a null check on `s`? Like in `@if (Model.Schedules.Any(s => s.User != null && s.User.Name != null && s.User.Name.Equals(User.Identity.Name)))`?

Comment: @user2609980 Yeah this is one of those situations where I just start putting null guards around the suspected areas and hope that fixes the issue.

Comment: @user2609980 Also `User.Identity` could be null if the user context hasn't been set.

Comment: Thanks. Why would it not been set? So also do null check on `User`, `User.Identity` and `User.Identity.Name`?

Comment: @user2609980 Not sure why it wouldn't be set. That one is probably a long shot.